# How do I map class object with Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, dapper

I am currently mapping the database query output to a class object in the following. Is there anyway I can directly map it with out using foreach loop?

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}


string select = "SELECT Id, Name, Address FROM emp where Id  = 100";

string dbConnection="Server = TestServer; userid = XXXX; password = YYYYY; database = TestDB; port = 1234";

Person person = new Person();

using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(dbConnection))
{
    var v = await connection.QueryAsync<Person>(select);
    if (v != null)
    {
        foreach (var res in v)
        {
            person.Id = res.Id;
            person.Name = res.Name;
            person.Address = res.Address;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't make logical sense as you are looping over a list of people & overwriting a single `Person` object with every new person being enumerated.

That aside, the result of `await connection.QueryAsync<Person>(select);` will be of type `IEnumerable<Person>`.

```
var v = await connection.QueryAsync<Person>(select);
```

is equal to:

```
IEnumerable<Person> = await connection.QueryAsync<Person>(select);
```

**You already have a collection of `Person` objects mapped.**